# The current path, FOUR/index/{ % url 'four:test' 1 %}, didn't match any of these

Tags: django

My template does not pass parameters and will not report an error, but the parameters will be reported incorrectly, please help me.

my urls.py is:

```
from django.urls import re_path

from FOUR import views

app_name = "four"
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'mmmm', views.mmmm, name='mmmm'),
    re_path(r'gettime/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<day>\d+)/$', views.gettime, name='gettime'),
]
```

my views.py is :

```
def mmmm(request):
    return render(request, 'test3.html')  
def gettime(request, year, day, month):
    return HttpResponse("time is %s-%s-%s" % (year, month, day))
```

my html is：

```
<a href="{ % url 'aaa:mmmm' % }">mmmmm</a><br>
<a href="{ % url 'gettime' year=2019 month=12 day=18 %}">cmdb/userinfo/tom/tomnickname/10</a><br>
```

mmmmm is OK，cmdb/userinfo/tom/tomnickname/10 The following error will occur

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MF6p.jpg)

error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/FOUR/index/%7B%20%25%20url%20'gettime'%20year%3D2019%20month%3D12%20day%3D18%20%25%20%7D
Using the URLconf defined in HelloDjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
APP/
TWO/
THREE
FOUR/ index/$
FOUR/ index/(\d+)
FOUR/ putstudent/$
FOUR/ mmmm [name='mmmm']
FOUR/ gettime/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<day>\d+)/$ [name='gettime']
The current path, FOUR/index/{ % url 'gettime' year=2019 month=12 day=18 % }, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Please include the output as text in the question, not pictures of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space between `{` and `%` in the url tags, so Django doesn't recognise it. Remove those.

Comment: thanks，I remove it，There will be new problems：'set' object is not reversible，I don't know how to solve

Comment: There will always be problems. Try to fix them, and if you can't open a new question on stack overflow, but not this way, you have to specifically create a new question per problem, detailing exactly that problem.

Comment: OK，I will open a new  question